# How to install python3-dateutil in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)?

Tags: aptitude, python3

I am trying to install the package `python3-dateutil` in a Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (Precise) with `aptitude`, but I cannot find it anywhere. How can I install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does the following command say?

```
apt-cache search python3-dateutil
```

If it shows python3-dateutil - powerful extensions to the standard datetime module in Python 3, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dateutil
```

Alternative is to install with pip:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: That command does not show anything. It seems like apt-get does not find it neither.

Comment: Try to install **python-pip** at first with the command: `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
After you will be able to install desired package with the command: `sudo pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: I have python-pip and python3-pip installed, so I can search for packages with pip and pip3 both. The problem is none of them are able to find python3-dateutil (I have python-dateutil installed, but I need the python3 version)

Comment: Try to install pip3: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and after that `sudo pip3 install python-dateutil`

Comment: OK, I was looking for the packages dateutil or python3-dateutil with pip3, but as you said, the package's name in pip3 is python-dateutil. Now I could install it!